# Integrate Google Analytics into VAST Preroll XML

Tags: xml, google-analytics, vast, preroll

I have a VAST Preroll XML file:

```
<VAST version="3.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Ad>
<InLine>
<Creatives>
<Creative>
<Linear skipoffset="00:00:05">
<Duration>00:00:30</Duration>
<VideoClicks>
<ClickThrough>https://www.url.com/</ClickThrough>
</VideoClicks>

<MediaFiles>
<MediaFile type="video/mp4">
<![CDATA[https://www.url.com/video.mp4]]>
</MediaFile>
</MediaFiles>
</Linear>
</Creative>
</Creatives>
</InLine>
</Ad>
</VAST>
```

I would like to track the number of views the video preroll get.

How can I integrate Google Analytics tracking code into the xml file?

Thank you.

Comment: You can not add a javascript tracking snippit to an xml file.

Comment: Then how could Google Analytics track hits on a VAST XML Preroll?